# Comparar con dos valores en consulta

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con Laravel y necesito es una bastante básica. Tengo una columna con el tipo de usuario y necesito buscar con administrador y usuario. Por ejemplo, algo como 'administrador || usuario'.

Ahora mismo sólo sé comparar con un valor usando `where` así:

```
 $variable = User::where('tipo', 'administrador')->get();
```

¿Cómo puedo comparar con dos o más valores en una consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `orWhere`

```
$variable = User::where('tipo', 'administrador')->orWhere('tipo', 'usuario')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar sobre dos o más valores, puedes usar el [método `whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries) que comprueba si el valor de la columna especificada está dentro de un array.

En tu caso la columna es `tipo` y los valores son "administrador" o "usuario", así que la llamada a `whereIn` sería así:

```
whereIn('tipo', ['administrador','usuario'])
```